# Json parse error Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, postman

I have the following controller that I am trying to test with Postman

```
public ResponseEntity<List<OldTransactionEntity>> createTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody List<OldTransactionNewDto> newDtos) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(transactionService.createTransactions(newDtos));
    }
```

The OldTransactionNewDto looks like this:

```
@Data
public class OldTransactionNewDto {
    @Min(0)
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private Integer depositConfirmationNumber;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate transactionDate;
    private TransactionTypes type;//TODO: Swap with enum? Now values are {1,2}
    @NotNull
    private Long lenderId;//TODO: Make db check with annotation or not?
    private Integer associatedAccountNumber;
    private Integer fileRequestId;//TODO: Remove?
    private String transferNotes;
    private LocalDateTime confirmationTime;
    private BigDecimal liquefied;
    private Boolean isNotifiedNotInvested;
    private String giTransactionId; //TODO: Remove?
    private Long transferId; //TODO: Remove?
    private Long originalTransactionRequestId; //TODO: Remove?
    private Boolean isInitialApproved; //TODO: Remove?

    private BankAccountNewDto parentBankAccount;
    private BankAccountNewDto childBankAccount;
}
```

The request json I am constructing in Postman is

```
{
    "amount" : 234,
    "depositConfirmationNumber" : 23,
    "transactionDate" : "2020-03-18",
    "type" : "DEPOSIT",
    "lenderId" : 2332,
    "associatedAccountNumber" : 32425,
    "fileRequestId" : 321,
    "transferNotes" : "note",
    "confirmationTime" : "2020-03-18",
    "liquefied" : 23412,
    "isNotifiedNotInvested" : false,
    "giTransactionId" : "245",
    "transferId" : 324,
    "originalTransactionRequestId" : 23,
    "isInitialApproved" : true,
    "parentBankAccount" : [
        {
            "userId" : 1,
            "bankAccountNumber" : 2,
            "bankNumber" : 123,
            "bankBranchNumber" : 2341,
            "bankDetails" : "details",
            "freeText" : "Free text"
        }],
    "childBankAccount" : [
        {
            "userId" : 1,
            "bankAccountNumber" : 2,
            "bankNumber" : 123,
            "bankBranchNumber" : 2341,
            "bankDetails" : "details",
            "freeText" : "Free text"
        }]  
}
```

I get MismatchInputException JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` so it is maybe because I need to provide List of OldTransactioNewDtos

Comment: You are deserializing an object into an `ArrayList`? Shouldn't it be deserialized into an `Object`? It looks like you need to wrap your object in a `List` and pass that along.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I am not sure what you are asking or what is the issue. I just want to hit this endpoint from Postman and provide the correct json structure that this endpoint wants

Comment: @GeorgiMichev at your java class, you have a simple object of BankAccountNewDto, but at the json you are passing as an array of BankAccountNewDto.

Take a look: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm

Comment: @MatheusRambo Indeed this was also issue - fixed it but I am still getting the error on line 1 column 1

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @MatheusRambo "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"

Comment: I got it. I saw that your controller you expect an array of OldTransactionNewDto, and your json request is passing a single object of it.